# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_posts() wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Im having a problem on how to register my own ajax to wordpress I already read [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and follow also [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/) tutorial but seems an error occur

**Error**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_posts() in
>   ...\copywriter-theme\orderer_creator_data.php:4
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   ...\copywriter-theme\orderer_creator_data.php
>   on line 4

This is the my **PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['type'])){
    $posts = get_posts(   //this is the line 4
            array(
                    'post_type'   => 'orderer',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'fields' => 'ids'
                )
            );
    $data = array();
    //loop over each post
    foreach($posts as $p){
        //get the meta you need form each post
        $data[] = array(
                "family_name" => get_post_meta($p,"family_name",true),
                "given_name" => get_post_meta($p,"given_name",true),
                "email" => get_post_meta($p,"e-mail_address",true),
                "reg_date" => $post->post_date,
                "last_mod" => $post->post_modified
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

My **Ajax**

```
$(".toggle").on("change",function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {type: $(".toggle option:selected").val()},
            success: function(result){
                $(".print").append(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

So far what I tried is to create a plugin and register their my ajax.

The **plugin**

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );

function my_script_enqueuer() {
    wp_register_script( "ajax_script", get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/copywriter.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax_script', 'Ajax_call', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_script' );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach it with a action, so that default function can be loaded before your code executes.

```
function handle_ajax_request(){
    if(isset($_POST['type'])){
    $posts = get_posts(   //this is the line 4
        array(
                'post_type'   => 'orderer',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'fields' => 'ids'
            )
        );
    $data = array();
    //loop over each post
    foreach($posts as $p){
        //get the meta you need form each post
        $data[] = array(
            "family_name" => get_post_meta($p,"family_name",true),
            "given_name" => get_post_meta($p,"given_name",true),
            "email" => get_post_meta($p,"e-mail_address",true),
            "reg_date" => $post->post_date,
            "last_mod" => $post->post_modified
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
    }


}

add_action( 'init', 'handle_ajax_request' );
```

Comment: thanks sir the error is gone but it return a zero data

Comment: You should send a unique value (e.g. 'my_action') in action index in ajax.. then you can add this function like add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'handle_ajax_request' ); and add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'handle_ajax_request' );

Comment: Read the tutorial carefully. You are missing many things . .https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/#handling-the-action-without-javascript